# Firebase Analytics events - is date range limited to 3 months back in time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

In the Firebase console you can view events from your apps.
However, in the date range picker it seems the maximum is "Quarter to date", which should get you the events for the last 90 days.
There is also a custom date option, but I cannot use that one to go back further in time it seems.

My questions is : is it really not possible to view events in Firebase that are older than 90 days?
If possible, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a <kbd>custom</kbd> date range, you can pick any range you want, including more than a quarter ago.

[image]

Click the little down arrow <kbd>⌄</kbd> next to the current date range

[image]

Click on <kbd>Custom...</kbd>.

[image]

Scroll up in the calendar to see dates further in the past.

Comment: Ah, you can scroll in the calendar!